# The genus of specialization of rational surface (compared to genus of parametrization)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Let $f(u,v),g(u,v),h(u,v)$ be polynomials with rational
coefficients or rational functions.

Assume (this happens in general) they parametrize 
rational surface $F(x,y,z)=0$.

For rational $a$, assume $h(u,v)=a$ defines curve of genus $g_h>1$.

Assume $G(x,y)=F(x,y,a)=0$ defines curve of genus $g_G$.

> Q1 Is it possible $0 < g_G < g_h$?

It is possible $g_G=0,g_h=2$.

Possible application is constructing curves with many rational points.

If we can choose $h(u,v)=a$, the larger the genus, the more rational 
$(x_i,y_i)$ points we can construct and this leads to 
$G(f(x_i,y_i),g(x_i,y_i))=F(f(x_i,y_i),g(x_i,y_i),h(x_i,y_i)=a)=0$.